# User defined function returns #REF in worksheet, works in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a simple UDF that tells me whether a currency code is G10 or not. It works fine when I test it in a sub in VBA but when I try to use it in a spreadsheet I get #REF.

```
Function IsG10(Cur As Range) As Boolean

  Dim G10s As Variant
  Dim Rslt As Boolean
  Dim Cross As Variant

 Cross = Cur.Value
 Rslt = False

 G10s = Array("USD", "GBP", "EUR", "CHF", "NOK", "SEK", "AUD", "NZD", "CAD", "JPY")

If Not (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Cross)) Or Len(Cross) > 3 Then
    IsG10 = CVErr(xlErrNA)
Else
    For Each i In G10s
        If Cross = i Then Rslt = True
    Next i
End If

IsG10 = Rslt

End Function
```

This is the Sub I'm using to test:

```
Sub Test()

 Dim TC As Range
 Dim ans As Variant
 Set TC = Range("Y53")

 ans = IsG10(TC)

End Sub
```

I've tried quite a few things to make it work, removed the error handling, returning a string instead of a bool... Nothing works. I can't see any obvious UDF mistakes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to rename your function.  `ISG10` is a valid cell address, so when you put a formula in a cell like `=ISG10(A1)`, Excel can't parse it correctly.  It works just fine when I change it to `Function Foobar(Cur As Range) As Boolean`.

Comment: You can have an hint on this with Excel changing `=IsG10(...)` to `=ISG10(...)` with all capitalized letters.

Comment: Will work if fully qualified as `=Module1.ISG10(C3)` where `module1` is the module name where the function is stored in. Not really a solution of course.

Comment: Good Catch @Comintern

Comment: FWIW, for a better performance, add `: Exit For` after `Rslt = True`. (+1)

Comment: Duly noted! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Huh, *another* reason to avoid cryptic meaningless names with a numeric suffix.