# Simple moving average range in Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel, average

This code is just to calculate simple moving average. Opened an excel, created dummy array in C row from 1 to 20. I want to create a function for eg: SMA(C7,3) = which should give average of C5:C7.

Coming back to VBA after long time, not able to figure whats the error in the below code.

```
Function sma1(rng As Range, N As Integer)
Set rng = rng.Resize(-N + 1, 0)
sma1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.average(rng)
End Function
```

Comment: Change the `0` in the Resize to `1`.  It is different than offset().

Comment: Just FYI, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38873678/4088852) illustrates the reason why you're getting recommendations to rename your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. avoid using a cell name as a function
2. fixed the `RESIZE()`
3. used an internal range variable

<strike>Function smal(rng As Range, N As Integer) As Variant
        Dim rng2 As Range
        Set rng2 = rng.Resize(N, 1)
        smal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng2)
    End Function</strike>

**EDIT#1:**

Based on Scott's comment:

```
Function smal(rng As Range, N As Integer) As Variant
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = rng.Offset(1 - N, 0).Resize(N, 1)
    smal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng2)
End Function
```

Comment: @ScottCraner  **Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the column along side it to give you're SMA (as shown below?):

[image]

If so, the below will do it and drag it autocomplete it to the bottom of you column C array:

```
Sub SMA3()
    Range("D7").FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-1]:RC[-1])" 'This is a relative reference (left one cell and up two cells) - This give your three inputs
    Range("D7").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D7:D" & Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row) 'Autofills the SMA
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI this can be done with existing formula:

```
=IF(ROW(C1)<$E$1,"",AVERAGE(INDEX(C:C,ROW(C1)-$E$1+1):C1))
```

E1 contains the number of rows to include.

[image]