# adjusting the formula with change in cell value in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate user defined simple moving average.
like if user enters 12 day simple moving average then excel should select first 12 values and then calculate average and if user change value to 50 or 200 then code should automatically change.

I can calculate for single value but i am not able to automate the complete process. this formula calculate 20 day SMA

```
Range("C21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-19]C[-1]:RC[-1])"
    Range("C21").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C21:C62")
    Range("C21:C62").Select
```

i want that excel should take user input like user enter 50 in D1 then code should select c51 and then code should change accordingly.
Thanks for your help

Comment: So you are asking how to use the contents of cell D1 instead of the `19` in the `"=AVERAGE(R[-19]C[-1]:RC[-1])"`?

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to make a UDF for use in the spreadsheet, this can be done with functions. Here is an example where you have to manually change the start and end indexes of your data:

```
=LET(
    Data, A1:A10,
    Start, 1,
    End,3,
    ArrayIndex, SEQUENCE(ROWS(Data)),
    ArrayMask, IF(ArrayIndex >= Start, IF(ArrayIndex <= End, TRUE, FALSE)),
    DataFiltered, FILTER(Data, ArrayMask),
    AVERAGE(DataFiltered)
)
```

And here it is generalized. Just put this next to your data and set `Range` to however long you need the window to be:

```
=LET(
    Data, $A$1:$A$10,
    Range, 2,
    RowStart, MIN(ROW(Data)),
    RowThis, ROW(),

    Start, RowThis - (Range - 1),

    ArrayIndex, SEQUENCE(ROWS(Data),1,RowStart),
    ArrayMask, IF(ArrayIndex >= Start, IF(ArrayIndex <= RowThis, TRUE, FALSE)),
    DataFiltered, FILTER(Data, ArrayMask),
    AVERAGE(DataFiltered)
)
```

Here is some vba you can try from [@Gary'sStudent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39452596/9393094).

```
Function smal(rng As Range, N As Integer) As Variant
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = rng.Offset(1 - N, 0).Resize(N, 1)
    smal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng2)
End Function
```

Comment: Please can you send me vba code for this